# How to submit the php page from jquery confirmation box?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I created a conformation box from jquery. I want to submit the page and view PHP echo message when click the confirm button in the confirmation box. Can you help me with code that comes for the confirmation button?

My jQuery/javascript function is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#click').click(function(){
//$(function() {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {

        // I WANT THE CODE FOR HERE TO SUBMIT THE PAGE TO WIEW PHP ECHO MESSAGE 
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery Form submit library. This will give you many options.
And according to your requirement you can call

```
beforeSubmit: 'YOUR FUNCTION To OPEN DIALOG',
```

If this returns true your form will get post and you will definitely get response.
see example here : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function...

```
$.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });
```

Here is a version with a callback when the post completed...

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   }
);
```

Or if you have an existing form that you want to post use the jQuery [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function...

```
$("form").submit();
```

But before you do this you need to make sure that you populated the input fields in the form.

Comment: @LahiruChathuranga If you don't want to submit any data then use the last example using the submit function. If you want to submit data use the second example using the post function, but I can't tell you how exactly because I don't know where you data comes from and what your server expects. Just change the second parameter of the post to have the key and values that you need { key: "value" }.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
var parameter_1 = 'test';
var parameter_2 = 'test';
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/submit_url.php",
            data: "parameter_1="+ parameter_1 +"& parameter_2 ="+ parameter_2,
            success: function(html)
            {
                   alert('Submitted');              
            }
        });
```

Comment: you have to set parameter_1 and parameter2